# What do elements of $k[x]/k[x^2,x^p]$ look like for some odd prime $p$ and field $k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I'm currently working through a problem related to $R = k[x]/k[x^2,x^p]$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $k$ a field.

It probably says a lot about my lack of understanding, but I think the elements are generated by $x$ and odd powers of $x$ up to but not including $x^p$. Is this the case?

Am I right in thinking that there is no constant term in any element, as $k \subset k[x^2,x^p]$?

In which case, the annihilator, $Ann(R) = \{0\}$?

This is my first question on stack exchange, so apologies if the formatting/style isn't correct.

Comment: The set $k[x^{2},x^{p}]$ is not an ideal of $k[x]$. For example, $1\in k[x^{2},x^{p}],$ and $x\in k[x]$, but $1\cdot x = x\not\in k[x^{2},x^{p}]$.

Comment: @WillR, but it is a submodule right? In which case the quotient can still make sense?

Comment: $k[x^{2},x^{p}]$ is the $k$-vector space gerated by $x^{2a+pb}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb N$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: @NicT It is not a $k[x]$-submodule, as the $R$-modules of $R$ are always just the ideals of $R$. It is a $k$-submodule, i.e., a $k$-linear subspace. In this context yes, the quotient still makes sense. Apologies for my confusion.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about the basis for $R$ as a $k$-vector space.  You start of with $k[x]$ which has basis $1,x,x^2,\cdots$ and then kill off all the basis elements except $x,x^3,x^5,\cdots, x^{p-2}$.  The annihilator, of any subset of a vector space (other than $\{ 0\}$ or $\emptyset$) is $\{0\}$.  As pointed out in previous comments $R$ is a $k$-vector space, but there is no obvious way to regard it as a $k[x]$ module: $$[x^3]=[x^2]x=[0]x=[0x]=[0]\neq[x^3], \qquad \text{for}\quad  p>3.$$

Comment: Thanks all for clearing this up! If this wraps up the question, do I need to mark it as closed or complete somehow? Or just leave it as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed by tkf(thank you!), my intuition was correct. $k[x]$ has basis $1,x,x^2,⋯$ and then in the quotient you 'kill off' all the basis elements except $x,x^3,x^5,⋯,x^{p-2}$. In which case, there is no constant term.

Also, the annihilator of any subset of a vector space (other than {0} or ∅) is {0}.